Measuring angle of a curve wire with OpenCV
I have a robotic device that bends wire, and I try to measure whether the bending was successful by looking at the desired and true angle measurements.
I'm very new to image processing so please excuse my crude terminology.

What I have in mind is to detect the wire and draw a line for each segment of the wire, after that it becomes just a little trigonometry problem. But I can not find a way to draw and get coordinates of those lines.

You should consider (and present) "How far can you simplify the problem?".
If you can establish some preconditions about input image (e.g. condition about noise, background, wire's {color, thickness, location, shape, exist}, etc), program can depends on them.
With no preconditions, it means "Any input image" and the problem will be very very difficult.

Thank you for your reply, I just updated the sample photo, the wire is black and the background is white.

needs a "machine vision" approach. deploy some sampling lines to locate the sections of the part you care about.

I'll post an answer this evening... I'd welcome one or two more pictures that show the expected variation of the object to measure (translation, rotation, bend angle, etc)

I would try these steps:

Skeletonize the image.
Get the relevant points from the skeleton-path.
Calculate the angle.

EDIT:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology, graph
from skan import Skeleton

def angle(v1, v2):
    rad = np.arctan2(v2[0], v2[1]) - np.arctan2(v1[0], v1[1])
    return np.abs((np.rad2deg(rad)))

# read an threshold image
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
inverted = 255 - gray
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(inverted, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# skeletonize image and split skeleton to paths, for now assume there is only one
skeleton = morphology.skeletonize(thresh, method='lee')
g = Skeleton(skeleton)
path = np.array(g.path_coordinates(0).astype(int))

# draw path for demonstration purpose
for p in path:
    img[p[0], p[1]] = [0, 0, 255]

# get reference points by percental position on path
l = len(path)
a1 = path[int(0.02 * l)]
a2 = path[int(0.10 * l)]
b1 = path[int(0.98 * l)]
b2 = path[int(0.90 * l)]

# results
print(f"Degrees: {angle(a1 - a2, b1 - b2):0.2f}")
cv2.line(img, (a1[1], a1[0]), (a2[1], a2[0]), [0, 255, 0], 2)
cv2.line(img, (b1[1], b1[0]), (b2[1], b2[0]), [0, 255, 0], 2)
cv2.imwrite("out.png", img)

Output:
Degrees: 32.32



Would be a better answer if you showed the code and an output from your code.

Thank you very much for your help. I will try the solution you said.

interesting approach!

I'll assume that the work piece always appears in roughly the same position, with some wiggle room.
This approach leans towards "machine vision", i.e. the types of operations you'd get from commercial MV programs that are made for automated optical inspection. Those programs let you "lay down" measurements visually and interactively. That saves a lot of trial and error, and coding.
I have manually picked regions in which the bent wire will be measured. For each region, I have defined the two end points, then declared there be five crossing lines along the length, across which I'll sample the image.

Those lines need not be straight. With more voodoo, you can easily have arcs for this, say if the end might be bent more or less. cv.polarToCart can help with that.

These are the samplings, 5 pixels tall, 101 pixels wide, enlarged, leftmost line first:


(And this is from the concentric arcs, inside out, and left is right... eh, just a matter of signs)

For each of the sampled lines, I calculate the gradient and find the min and max in there. That should be the edges of the work piece along each line.
Here's a plot across one of them, with gradient:

And here are the points in the picture corresponding to these extrema:

Then I take the midpoint for each of those, and fit a line through.

The angle between both lines (their vectors) is then about ~30 degrees.

This has some corner cases, such as what happens if a sampling line doesn't intersect the work piece, like I provoked at the tip of the "working end". You can see how marginal this is in the 101 x 5 pixel samplings.
Such cases can be handled by assessing the magnitudes of the extrema, and discarding the line if that's too small.

Code coming right up...
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm, inv
import cv2 as cv

# utility functions

def vec(*a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        (a,) = a
    return np.asarray(a)

def normalize(v):
    return np.asarray(v) / norm(v)

def translate2(dx=0, dy=0):
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[0:2, 2] = [dx, dy]
    return T

def scale2(s=1, sx=1, sy=1):
    return np.diag([s*sx, s*sy, 1])

def normal2(v):
    x,y = v
    return np.asarray([-y, +x])

def to_basis(origin, ax, ay):
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[0:2, 0] = ax
    T[0:2, 1] = ay
    T[0:2, 2] = origin
    return T

def index_grid(nx, ny=1):
    return np.mgrid[0:ny, 0:nx].transpose(1, 2, 0)[:,:,::-1]

def transform_grid(H, grid):
    (h, w, inner_dim) = grid.shape
    assert inner_dim == 2
    output_points = cv.transform(
        src=grid.reshape( (-1, 1, inner_dim) ).astype(np.float32),
        m=H)
    # hoping [..., 2] is all ones
    output_points = output_points[..., :-1]
    output_points.shape = (h, w, inner_dim)
    return output_points

def grid_along_line(p0, p1, width, nx, ny):
    v0 = p1 - p0
    length = norm(v0)
    v0 = v0 / length
    dx = width / (nx-1)
    dy = length / (ny-1)
    grid = index_grid(nx, ny)
    T = scale2(sx=dx, sy=dy) @ translate2(-(nx-1)/2, 0)
    T = to_basis(p0, -normal2(v0), v0) @ T
    grid = transform_grid(T, grid)
    return T, grid

def get_midpoints(sampled, T):
    midpoints = []

    for i, row in enumerate(sampled):
        grad = np.gradient(row)

        jrising = np.argmax(grad)
        jfalling = np.argmin(grad)

        # vrising = grad[jrising]
        # vfalling = grad[jfalling]
        # print(vrising - vfalling)

        p_rising = T @ vec(jrising, i, 1)
        p_falling = T @ vec(jfalling, i, 1)
        p_mid = (p_rising + p_falling) / 2

        midpoints.append(p_mid[:2])

    return np.asarray(midpoints)


im = 255 - cv.imread("JqI70V2C.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
(height, width) = im.shape[:2]

# manually defined bands across which to take sample lines

working_end_p0 = vec(376, 315)
working_end_p1 = vec(585, 181)
T_working_end, working_end_grid = grid_along_line(working_end_p0, working_end_p1, 200.0, 101, 5)

standing_end_p0 = vec(4, 505)
standing_end_p1 = vec(678, 487)
T_standing_end, standing_end_grid = grid_along_line(standing_end_p0, standing_end_p1, 200.0, 101, 5)

working_end_sampled = cv.remap(im, map1=working_end_grid, map2=None, interpolation=cv.INTER_LANCZOS4)
standing_end_sampled = cv.remap(im, map1=standing_end_grid, map2=None, interpolation=cv.INTER_LANCZOS4)

vecs = []
for (sampled, T) in [
        (working_end_sampled, T_working_end),
        (standing_end_sampled, T_standing_end)
    ]:
    points = get_midpoints(sampled, T)

    cov = np.cov(points.T)

    (eigenvalues, eigenvectors) = np.linalg.eig(cov) # column vectors

    major_axis = eigenvectors[:, np.argmax(eigenvalues)]

    x_ = points[:,0].mean()
    y_ = points[:,1].mean()
    p0 = vec(x_, y_)
    v = normalize(vec(major_axis))

    vecs.append(v)


[v1, v2] = vecs
angle = np.arccos(v1 @ v2)
print(f"{np.degrees(angle):.1f} deg")

I have skipped the visualizations because they're fairly trivial (a circle() call for each point). In the last loop, you can draw lines with this:
canvas = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# draw major axis
cv.line(
    img=canvas,
    pt1=(p0 - 1000*v).round().astype(int),
    pt2=(p0 + 1000*v).round().astype(int),
    color=(0, 255, 0),
    thickness=2)


if you have any further questions, please let me know. if this answer solves your problem, you can let people know by marking it as "accepted" with the checkmark. the purpose of this is presented in the site's [tour].

The points working_end_p0, working_end_p1, standing_end_p0, standing_end_p1 are all taken manually. Is there any way to automatically determine these points?

they are process parameters. their exact position doesn't matter. they only need to capture the area in which the segments are expected to lie. -- I had to generalize from a single example. I did my best to anticipate variation. if you have a picture for which my answer doesn't work, please show me the picture.

Thanks @Christoph Rackwitz. I will update new photos.
